# Java Graphics2D streaming?

Tags: java, streaming, video-streaming, graphics2d

Is there a way in java to use Graphics2D API to paint on screen of remote java process?
Any API to stream and deserialize painting instructions?

Or I have to use my own "api call" serialization/deserialization mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends on the kind of media you're dealing with. If you're playing video, the codec you're using might have be APIs to do this, but you'll need to search around to find out. Graphics2D is really meant for more primitive painting operations, such as drawing shapes, rendering text, and copying image data from place to place.

If you're writing your own streaming algorithm, then it could be as simple as defining a `PaintEvent` class that does what you need. The idea of the `PaintEvent` class would be that it contains instructions of what to do. For example, if you draw a circle with radio 50 on the remote system, then rather than transmit the pixel data over the network, it's much more efficient to transmit a message that basically says, "draw a circle with radius 50" across the network, and have the client render it on their side.

A PaintEvent class, I would think, would look something like this:

```
public class PaintEvent {
  public static final int OPER_DRAW_CIRCLE = 0;
  public static final int OPER_DRAW_RECT   = 1;
  public static final int OPER_DRAW_TEXT   = 2;
  ...etc...

  int paintOperationID;
  int[] paintDetails;           // where 'paintDetails' contains data such as a circle's radius, a rectangle's dimensions, the (x, y) location where to render text, etc.
  java.awt.Color renderColor;
  String text;

  public PaintEvent(int paintOperationID, int[] paintDetails, Color renderColor, String text) {
     ...
  }

}
```

So, depending on what the `paintOperationID` is, it would treat the data in `paintDetails` differently. And unless it's a `OPER_DRAW_TEXT` operation, the `text` field would just be ignored.

This is one way to do it, anyway. Then you just design a communications protocol around this, to get the data from one place to another.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this way in case if there isn't any other solutions. Solution for this problem is pretty straightforward, and I thought that anyone already have it ready for using - Graphics2d proxy, IO/streaming, message handler, connected to another graphics2d.

Comment: But it seems that I should implement message handler by myself

Comment: That's what I would recommend. It shouldn't take long, and I doubt that if anyone else has done it, that it's something they would release. Java2D isn't exactly a heavily used library for a lot of 2D graphics. From here, 2D graphics in Java get very specialized (i.e. graphics for games), and have libraries dedicated to the application space which they serve.